# spring neo4j get two list of different labels but the same relationship

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

```
public class Company implements Serializable {
    @RelatedTo(type = "REPORT_TO", direction = Direction.INCOMING)
    private List<Department> departments;

    @RelatedTo(type = "REPORT_TO", direction = Direction.INCOMING)
    private List<Company> subCompanies;
```

In class Company, there are two list with different labels (Department and Company),

but when I use neo4jTemplate.fetch(company.getSubCompanies()), the result is the total of departments and subCompanies. **It seems spring-neo4j search results by relationship, and search all the label, not the specific one**

So why the departments will return ? And the amazing thing is that 
   `@Override
    public List<Company> getSubCompaniesByCompanyId(Long companyId) {
        Company company = companyRepository.findOne(companyId);
        return neo4jTemplate.fetch(company.getSubCompanies());
    }`

the chrome console will get the Department bean, how can it convert to Company.......

Add the beans to see the amazing
[image]
[image]
**and the console result**

[image]

The properties has "departmentType", which is the property of Department, but now in the bean of Company.....
And I've seen in java, the bean in List is Department!!!
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to use the annotation attribute: `enforceTargetType=true` which should limit the types to the one given in the target. (You might need to use `elementClass=Department.class` as well, can't remember exactly)